# Bash compare if two strings match by length

Tags: bash, string-length

I have two string variables that I need to compare by length inside of `if`. So I need to do something like this:

```
if [ length($string_one) != length($string_two) ]:

fi
```

Comment: See: [String length of bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17750940/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [[ ${#string} != ${#string_two} ]]; then
    run command
fi
```